# OrderedDict skips entries with NaN values

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddict

why does OrderedDict and a normal dict behave differently?

When I put two entries with NaNs in my dictionary the OrderedDict just skips them and does not recognize them.

I tried to put the entries in different order, also trying "NaN" but nothing helped

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np

ordered_dict = OrderedDict([(np.nan, 0), (np.nan, 0.01), (np.nan, 
0.02)])


print(ordered_dict)
```

results in

```
OrderedDict([(nan, 0.02)])
```

but

```
normal_dict = {(np.nan, 0), (np.nan, 0.01), (np.nan, 0.02)}

print(normal_dict)
```

is

```
{(nan, 0.02), (nan, 0), (nan, 0.01)}
```

Comment: Your `OrderedDict` doesn't skip `nan` values, it simply updates duplicated keys and takes the last value provided

Answer (score 1):

your second example is a `set` of `tuples` (three different ones) and not a `dict`:

```
type({(np.nan, 0.02), (np.nan, 0), (np.nan, 0.01)})
# <class 'set'>
```

a `dict` would be created this way (and behave as expected):

```
normal_dict = dict(((np.nan, 0), (np.nan, 0.01), (np.nan, 0.02)))
# {nan: 0.02}
```

for both types a key (`np.nan`) can appear once only - therefore the other entries get lost (as they should).

depending on your needs you probably need a different data structure to hold your data.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the OrderedDict class is overwriting values with the same key. Note that if you change the order of the list the result will change too:

```py
ordered_dict = OrderedDict([(np.nan, 0), (np.nan, 0.02), (np.nan, 0.01)])

print(ordered_dict)  # OrderedDict([(nan, 0.01)])
```